# Получение временного интервала, начальное время и массив временных отметок

Tags: javascript

Помогите пожалуйста составить данный скрипт.

В общем задача такая, это типа временной график, нужно получить значение `start` и `cols_array`

В данном коде проблема, дело в том что колонки должны идти точно по минутно (12:00, 12:01, 12:02, и т.д.) . Ни знаю как по другому объяснить, надеюсь что проблема кода ясна

```js
let interval = 60; // 60 секунд = 1 минута
let cols = 10; // 10 колонок, где 9 колонок это 9 минут, а последняя оставшееся время до текущего времени
let now = new Date().getTime(); // текущее время, время в последней колонки

let start = now - (interval * cols); // Самое начально время в формате new Date().getTime()
let cols_array = []; // массив из 10 подмассивов, здесь интервал времени на каждую колонку
for(let i = 0; i < cols; i++){
  cols_array[i] = [new Date(now), new Date(now - (interval * 1000))];
  now = now - (interval * 1000);
}

console.log(new Date(start)); // время самой первой колонки, секунды должны быть 00
console.log(cols_array); // секунды должны быть 00

// interval, cols это меняющиеся значения
```

Answer (score 2):

Не знаю правильно ли я понял, что нужно обнулить секунды? Как вариант просто отнимите количество секунд от начальной временной метки

```
let dateObj = new Date();
let now = dateObj.getTime() - dateObj.getSeconds()*1000;
```